# how to know how many bits a microcontroller has?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, architecture

How can I know what kind of architecture a microcontroller has?
For example where can I read in the datasheet of the pic 16F873 how many bits architecture is? 8, 16, 32?

Next question what does:
What does mean:   Up to 256 x 8 bytes of EEPROM Data Memory.
Mean that there are 256 slots of 8 bytes? Or (256 x 8) bytes? So 256 slots of 8 bit each?
I don’t think it’s explained really well :S.
Thx for answers :)

Comment: Read the datasheet.  That's how you learn the internal workings of a particular microcontroller (and any other IC for that matter).

Comment: It's perfectly well explained, you just need to understand the technical jargon.

Comment: "256 x 8 bytes" ? sure you don't mean 8 **bits**?

Answer (score 5):

With PICs in particular, sometimes you find what you need in the [Family Reference Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33023a.pdf) as opposed to the data sheet.  In this case, the mid-range family ref manual has a chapter on architecture that you might find of use, and its in a different tone than the chip's datasheet.

For PICs datasheets tend to have a ton of chip specific info,but the Family Ref Manuals tend to show a more global picture.

Comment: Sorry, -1 because I don't like answers that say "there is PDF with 688 pages and you can find answer there".

Comment: @Kamil  People keep pointing to the data sheet, and that's not necessarily the best resource for this type of question.  In learning PICs it took me a while to realize that the family refs existed, and that sometimes they're valuable, so I thought I'd provide the shortcut for a new user.  There was no need to repeat the info in the answers already provided.  I was a bit divided on commenting vs answering, but I thought there was enough archival value to make this an answer

Comment: OK, you convinced me. Please edit something so I can rollback my downvote.

Comment: +1 for pointing people at the right documentation - especially one many might not realize exists!

Answer (score 3):

Page 1 top of the page then further down in the architecture there are the clues: -

[image]

256 x 8 usually means 256 bytes each byte is 8 bits wide.

Comment: The 'up to' part is caused by the fact that the datasheet describes multiple devices: the 16F873 that has 128 bytes EPROM, and the 16F876 that has 256 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet states categorically the core CPU size on the title page:

## 28/40-Pin 8-Bit CMOS FLASH

The EEPROM is arranged in 8-bit bytes, and there are 256 of them.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Harvard architecture 8-bit processor with a 14-bit instruction width.

That's why a 4096-word program memory is listed as 7.2K (7168) bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The 16F873 is an 8-bit microcontroller. Its internal registers are 8 bits wide. The data sheet should say so, but maybe it assumes you already know that -- the person writing it may have thought it was too obvious to mention. The internal RAM and EEPROM are also 8 bits wide.

As for the EEPROM, 256 x 8 in this context means 256 8-bit locations in the memory. 256 slots of 8 bits each. It's not well explained, by the sound of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Microchip microcontroller families.

8-bit: PIC10, PIC12, PIC16, PIC18

16bit: PIC24, PIC30, PIC33

32bit: PIC32

If you go to Microchip website and enter microcontrollers ([link](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/products/picmicrocontrollers)) you will see these families on the left side.

---

Regarding 256 x 8 bytes - I agree that this may mislead.

256 x 8 means: 256 directly addressable 8-bit registers of memory (256*8 bits).

Each byte has separate address.

```
address  data
0x0000   xxxxxxxx (byte 0)
0x0001   xxxxxxxx (byte 1)
0x0002   xxxxxxxx (byte 2)
0x0003   xxxxxxxx (byte 3)
```

If that would be

256 x 16 - thay would be 512 bytes, but only 256 directly addressable (you have to store 16 bits at once) and you cannot directly access each byte.

```
address  data
0x0000   xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx (byte 0, byte 1) 
0x0001   xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx (byte 2, byte 2)
```

In Intel x86 - most of registers are 32-bit wide. You cannot read only one byte, you have to read whole register to get one byte from it.